# grep a large list against a large file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

I am currently trying to `grep` a large list of ids (~5000) against an even larger csv file (3.000.000 lines).

I want all the csv lines, that contain an id from the id file.

My naive approach was:

```
cat the_ids.txt | while read line
do
  cat huge.csv | grep $line >> output_file
done
```

But this takes forever!

Are there more efficient approaches to this problem?

Comment: To find all of the strings inside a file, you can run grep in FOR loop: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462445/43233

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try

```
grep -f the_ids.txt huge.csv
```

Additionally, since your patterns seem to be fixed strings, supplying the `-F` option might speed up `grep`.

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 25):

Use `grep -f` for this:

```
grep -f the_ids.txt huge.csv > output_file
```

From `man grep`:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

If you provide some sample input maybe we can even improve the `grep` condition a little more.

#### Test

```
$ cat ids
11
23
55
$ cat huge.csv 
hello this is 11 but
nothing else here
and here 23
bye

$ grep -f ids huge.csv 
hello this is 11 but
and here 23
```

Answer (score 13):

`grep -f filter.txt data.txt` gets unruly when `filter.txt` is larger than a couple of thousands of lines and hence isn't the best choice for such a situation. Even while using `grep -f`, we need to keep a few things in mind:

- use `-x` option if there is a need to match the entire line in the second file
- use `-F` if the first file has strings, not patterns
- use `-w` to prevent partial matches while not using the `-x` option

This post has a great discussion on this topic (`grep -f` on large files):

- [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash)

And this post talks about `grep -vf`:

- [grep -vf too slow with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702425/grep-vf-too-slow-with-large-files?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

**In summary, the best way to handle `grep -f` on large files is:**

Matching entire line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} $0 in hash' filter.txt data.txt > matching.txt
```

Matching a particular field in the second file (using ',' delimiter and field 2 in this example):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {hash[$1]; next} $2 in hash' filter.txt data.txt > matching.txt
```

**and for `grep -vf`:**

Matching entire line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > not_matching.txt
```

Matching a particular field in the second file (using ',' delimiter and field 2 in this example):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} !($2 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > not_matching.txt
```