# Fastest way to find lines in file1 which contains any keywords from file2?

Tags: shell, file, file-comparison, data-comparison

I have two files.  The first file has three hundred thousand records shown example (`file1`) and second file has one hundred thousand records, shown example (`file2`). I am basically doing a grep of each entry on `file2` with `file1` and retrieve all that is in file1. I am doing this with a normal for loop:

```
for i in `cat file2.txt`; do cat file1 | grep -i -w $i; done > /var/tmp/file3.txt
```

As the data is too huge it takes me 8+ hours to complete this operation.. I need your expertise in giving me an option on how can I do this in an efficient way to deliver this in less than 2-3 hours.

Example entries

File1

```
server1:user1:x:13621:22324:User One:/users/user1:/bin/ksh |  
server1:user2:x:14537:100:User two:/users/user2:/bin/bash |  
server1:user3:x:14598:24:User three:/users/user3:/bin/bash |  
server1:user4:x:14598:24:User Four:/users/user4:/bin/bash |  
server1:user5:x:14598:24:User Five:/users/user5:/bin/bash |
```

File2

```
user1  
user2  
user3
```

Comment: when I had a similar problem, I had to recompile grep so the buffer used by the `-Ff` options would take the whole search-target file in. It's possible that the `gnu` -`F` option is autosizing it's memory consumption. But use `man grep` and read about `-F` . Also see if there is a LIMITATIONS section. Else you can build a similar tool with `awk` (assuming enough free memory to hold all of `file2`. Search here for similar Qs that have been posted. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shelter, thanks for the reply, this is whats in man page, what you are suggesting me to is do an grep -fF and see if that helps?   -F                 Matches using fixed strings. Treats  each
                        pattern  specified as a string instead of
                        a regular expression. If  an  input  line
                        contains  any  of  the patterns as a con-
                        tiguous sequence of bytes,  the  line  is
                        matched.  A  null  string  matches  every
                        line. See fgrep(1) for more information.

Comment: This can be considered a duplicate of so many similar posts in here. For example see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash/42239352#42239352

Comment: thanks George, you are right I can take few things from the post you shared, which will help me to get what I am looking for. thank you so much, i will mark this question as complete.

Comment: In the mean time , cat +grep is a terrible choice. You can grep a file firectly, you don't need a cat first. You can also automatically feed the grep with patterns and you don't even need a loop for file2. Thus said, you can substitute your whole code with a simple command : `grep -f file2 file1` or even better `grep -F -f file2 file1`. Don't be afraid to use the -F.

Comment: Awesome, i will try that. thanks so much George.

Comment: Let us know about your time test results....

Comment: For a quicker solution, maybe less than couple of minutes, see my perl solution for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42302653/6920976 , if you  choose to use that script, just run ./comp.pl "file2.txt" "file1.txt" (for your case as there it must be file1 and then file2). Thanks.

Comment: Looks like -f and -F not working for me root@server1 # grep -i -F -f file2 file1 > file3
grep: illegal option -- F
grep: illegal option -- f
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
root@server1 # grep -i -fF file2 file1 > file3
grep: illegal option -- f
grep: illegal option -- F
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: Try `grep -Ff file2 file1` . Leave -i out of the game for testing.

Comment: That too didnt work, I am using Solaris 5.10, where its not working but I used a Redhat server and looks like the command(grep -i -F -f file2 file1 > file3) is trying to get executed there. waiting for it to get completed. I may may need to get this worked in solaris server because Redhat server is just one of the test server. In mean time i will go through the perl script posted by "Useless Person"

Comment: OK. For future comments, start your comment with @user in order users to be notified.

Comment: as your man page told you, "see `fgrep(1)` So `fgrep -f file2 file1`.  But given that you have a system that has `fgrep`, it probably won't be able to read all of `file2` into memory. If it doesn't work then use one of the other solutions above. Also, given your (seemingly non-linux OS), you'll do well to indicate output of `uname -srv` in all of your questions going forward. Good luck.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136120/discussion-on-question-by-binish-fastest-way-to-find-lines-in-file1-which-contai).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep a large list against a large file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380925/grep-a-large-list-against-a-large-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

**Test Data:**

```
%_Host@User> head file1.txt file2.txt
==> file1.txt <==
server1:user1:x:13621:22324:User One:/users/user1:/bin/ksh |
server1:user2:x:14537:100:User two:/users/user2:/bin/bash |
server1:user3:x:14598:24:User three:/users/user3:/bin/bash |
server1:user4:x:14598:24:User Four:/users/user4:/bin/bash |
server1:user5:x:14598:24:User Five:/users/user5:/bin/bash |

==> file2.txt <==
user1
user2
user3
#user4
%_Host@User>
```

**Output:**

```
    %_Host@User> ./2comp.pl file1.txt file2.txt   ; cat output_comp
    server1:user1:x:13621:22324:User One:/users/user1:/bin/ksh |
    server1:user3:x:14598:24:User three:/users/user3:/bin/bash |
    server1:user2:x:14537:100:User two:/users/user2:/bin/bash |
    %_Host@User>
    %_Host@User>
```

**Script:** Please give this one more try. Re-check the file order. File1 first and then file second: `./2comp.pl file1.txt file2.txt`.

```
%_Host@User> cat 2comp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my ($file2,$file1,$output) = (@ARGV,"output_comp") ;
my (%hash,%tmp) ;

(scalar @ARGV != 2 ? (print "Need 2 files!\n") : ()) ? exit 1 : () ;

for (@ARGV) {
  open FH, "<$_" || die "Cannot open $_\n" ;
  while (my $line = <FH>){$line =~ s/^.+[()].+$| +?$//g ; chomp $line ; $hash{$_}{$line} = "$line"}
  close FH ;}

open FH, ">>$output" || die "Cannot open outfile!\n" ;
foreach my $k1 (keys %{$hash{$file1}}){
  foreach my $k2 (keys %{$hash{$file2}}){
    if ($k2 =~ m/^.+?$k1.+?$/i){    # Case Insensitive matching.
      if (!defined $tmp{"$hash{$file2}{$k2}"}){
        print FH "$hash{$file2}{$k2}\n" ;
        $tmp{"$hash{$file2}{$k2}"} = 1 ;
                }}}} close FH  ;
# End.
%_Host@User>
```

Thanks good luck.

Comment: Dear friend you did the job, that worked. Awesome..Only thing I checked again was the case sensitive scenario, I did a small test changing the entry in file2, making user3 to USER3, that didnt work. Will that be simple change?can you consider that too? because file2 may have entries like that.

Comment: Please see my updated comment in the script. It should do it!

Comment: Thanks So much that did the work. I will now try to run this on my Three hundred thousand record and going to see how long its going to take. Thanks Again friend.