# grep -vf too slow with large files

Tags: bash, performance, shell, awk, grep

I am trying filter data from data.txt using patterns stored in a file filter.txt. Like below,

```
grep -v -f filter.txt data.txt > op.txt
```

This grep takes more than 10-15 minutes for 30-40K lines in filter.txt and ~300K lines in data.txt.

Is there any way to speed up this?

data.txt

```
data1
data2
data3
```

filter.txt

```
data1
```

op.txt

```
data2
data3
```

This works with solution provided by codeforester but fails when filter.txt is empty.

Comment: Please include sample lines from both the files.  You may want to take a look at this post which has extensive discussion on this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for links. Good discussion about similar problem. awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}$2 in hash' file1.txt FS='|' file2.txt works for matching lines but need inverted results. Not sure how to make it work for invert match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [Inian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015) solution in the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash) post, this `awk` command should solve your issue:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > op.txt
```

Comment: Yup. Found it . Thanks:)

Comment: This command returns empty op.txt file if filter.txt is empty though data.txt has lines. In ideal case, it should return all records from data.txt

Comment: Works correctly for me.  Are there leading/trailing spaces in your files?

Comment: awk statement is used is loop with some condition. Because of that condition sometimes filter.txt is empty and that time I get op.txt as empty though data.txt has data lines. In this case, op.txt should be equal to data.txt as pattern to match is nothing (filter.txt is empty).

Comment: I tried fixing but my methods don't seem to work. Hope @karakfa can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help @codeforester. I'll post as seperate question to make it available to more audience

Comment: Please do.  `awk 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; n++; next} (!($0 in hash) || n == 0)' file1 file2` didn't work, by the way.  Neither did `awk 'BEGIN {hash[""]=0;} FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' file1 file2`.

Comment: Just for the record the method `!($0 in hash)` does not work for me either. It has to be `(!($0 in hash))`.

Comment: `(!($0 in hash))` is same as `!($0 in hash)` - an extra `()` doesn't make a difference. And it doesn't solve the issue of `awk` not producing any output when `filter.txt` has nothing.