# Handle empty file in awk file comparison

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to find records from data.txt which are not matching data in filter.txt. Earlier I used `grep -vf filter.txt data.txt` which was working correctly but was very slow.

As per discussion in [grep -vf too slow with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702425/grep-vf-too-slow-with-large-files) I switched to

```
awk 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > op.txt
```

which works if filter.txt is not empty.

data.txt

```
data1
data2
data3
```

filter.txt

```
data1
```

op.txt

```
data2
data3
```

but fails if filter.txt is empty. If filter.txt is empty then output op.txt is also empty. Ideally it should be equal to data.txt.

Tried with ARGIND==1. Seems to work for empty filter.txt but producing wrong results for non-empty filter.txt. Expected output is present above.

```
$ cat filter.txt 
abc2
$ awk 'ARGIND==1{hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > op.txt
$ cat op.txt 
abc2
abc1
abc2
abc3
$ vi filter.txt 
$ cat filter.txt 
$ awk 'ARGIND==1{hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt > op.txt
$ cat op.txt 
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

Comment: You can use `ls -s` to see if a file is empty and if that matches 0 then skip that file, or if you want an all awk solution then check is `NR > 2` and only process if so, or similar (something like `awk 'END{print(NR>2)?"NOT EMPTY":"EMPTY"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FNR==FNR` to `ARGIND==1` if you have GNU awk or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` otherwise.

```
$ awk --version | head -1
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2)

$ awk 'ARGIND==1{hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt
data2
data3

$ awk --posix 'ARGIND==1{hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt
data1
data1
data2
data3

$ awk --posix 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{hash[$0]; next} !($0 in hash)' filter.txt data.txt
data2
data3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but above solution works if filter.txt is empty but produces wrong results if filter.txt is not empty. I am looking for a solution that takes care of both cases.

Comment: No, it does not produce incorrect results. Try again.

Comment: I tried again but still incorrect results. I have updated question with the results. Please have a look.

Comment: As I said, "use `ARGIND==1` **if you have GNU awk**". If `ARGIND==1` isn't working for you then clearly you aren't using GNU awk. I updated the answer to show the GNU vs POSIX functionality.

Comment: Yes. Mawk was installed on my machine. It works with gawk. Thanks a lot.