# How to pipeline cat to sed pattern

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I want to pipline cat output of file to a sed pattern.
Suppose I have 2 files: color.txt and duplicate.txt. color.txt contain 3 colors: blue, green, red and duplicate.txt contains green.
I want to use sed to delete green from color.txt file.

I try something like this:

```
cat duplicate.txt | sed "/$/d" < color.txt
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: *nix utils can generally work on files and using cat in this way is broadly considered to be a "[UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)" ... a "useless use of cat".  As you'll see in the answers (so far) they generally don't use `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to achieve what you want:

```
grep -Fxvf duplicate.txt color.txt
```

- `-F` to treat lines in duplicate.txt as strings rather than patterns
- `-x` to match whole lines in color.txt
- `-v` to extract lines that don't match
- `-f` to pick up strings from duplicate.txt to match against color.txt

This will work irrespective of how many patterns your files have.  For extremely large files, you might want to take a look at this post:

- [Fastest way to find lines of a text file from another larger text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711996/3815539

Answer (score 2):

While in this case the `grep` solution is enough, sometimes I use a command like this:

`sed 's|.*|/^\1$/d|' duplicate.txt | sed -i -f - color.txt`

Here the first `sed` invocation converts each line from duplicate.txt into a proper `sed` command to delete exactly what needed. This results in a `sed` script that is then passed to second `sed` using `-f -` where the `-` file name means standard input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
sed "/$(cat duplicate.txt)/d" color.txt
```

However, as you can tell from the comments, this approach is not very advisable. I urge you to use one of the other solutions. I won't delete this answer though, as it does show the technique you wanted to learn.

Comment: Wouldn't this give a syntax error if duplicate.txt has more than one line?  Also, it will delete lines that match partially as well.  Not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: @codeforester Yes, I took the question to mean there was only one line because of the example given and the fact that it is called *"duplicate"* and not *"duplicates"*. Although I guess by that logic, it should be *"colors.txt"* but it isn't:-)

Comment: The partial matches could be overcome by adding word boundaries, but again OP wasn't specific on that matter. I was trying to demonstrate the technique OP was asking about - namely how to use contents of a file as the pattern for `sed`. I agree your solution is technically more accurate, mine is closer to the concept OP appeared to be trying to achieve - going by the title. I'll vote for yours

Comment: I hope the color doesn't has a slash, like `terrible/red`.