# Find only those IDs from a list that are present in both of 2 data files

Tags: file, search, grep

I have a text file `IDs.txt` containing one unique ID string per line e.g.:

```
foo
bar
someOtherID
```

I know that **some** of these IDs are found in **one or both** of 2 other files with differently formatted data lines, `1.txt` and `2.txt`

```
1.txt
id=foo
name=example
age=81
end
id=notTheIDYouAreLookingFor
name=other
age=null
```

```
2.txt
<Data>
<ID>foo</ID>
<Stuff>Some things</Stuff>
</Data>
<Data>
<ID>bar</ID>
<Stuff>Other things</Stuff>
</Data>
```

The specific data formats are not important since all I need to answer is "which IDs are in both?", and indeed **ideally I need a format-independent solution**

In the example I want to find the lines with `foo`:

`<ID>foo</ID>`
`id=foo`

Effectively: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380925/grep-a-large-list-against-a-large-file) but grepping the large list of IDs against 2 files instead of 1 and finding the common hits.

Comment: `s/The specific data formats are not important/The specific data formats are all-important/`. You can't write a tool that magically knows that within some file some string `foo` is an ID as opposed to a name or Stuff or a tag instead of a value or anything else without knowing/parsing the format of that file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to find out the ids in both files (f1 and f2), you don't have to parse the `ids.txt`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a["<ID>"$1"</ID>"]="id="$1;next}
    a[$0]{print $0,a[$0]}' <(grep -oP 'id=\K.*' f1) f2
```

the above one-liner outputs:

```
<ID>foo</ID> id=foo
```

Comment: But that is not data format independent, is it? I need to configure it to whatever markup pattern is in my data files, correct?

Comment: @Michael in your question you said, "data formats are not improtant". It cannot be true. Otherwise, how can you tell, where the id value is located in a file?  we parse json, xml, text, csv... formats via different logic.  You cannot say, hey, here is my file no matter what format it has, give me the id value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for GNU awk, far from perfect:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                      # store file1 entries to a[1]
    a[ARGIND][$0]
    next
}
match($0,/([iI][dD][>=])([^<]+)/,arr) {        # hash on whats =after or >between<
    a[ARGIND][arr[2]]=$0                       # store whole record. key on above
}
END {
    for(i in a[1])                             # get keywords from first file
        if((i in a[2]) && (i in a[3]))         # if found in files 2 and 3
            print a[2][i],a[3][i]              # output
}' file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
id=foo <ID>foo</ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an `awk` expert so I tend to break things into chunks when a one-liner might do.

I'm going to assume that you've taken to heart the earlier comment that a simple format-independent solution is unlikely.  Instead, I've taken the approach of documenting the format inside the script, and normalizing the two input formats.  If a third format appears, then just modify the script to document and normalize that new format.

```
$ cat << EOF > work.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 1.txt has IDs in the form id=....

grep -x 'id=.*' 1.txt | sed -e 's/^id=//' | sort > 1.txt.ids

# 2.txt has IDs in the form <ID>...</ID>

grep -x '^<ID>.*</ID>' 2.txt | sed -Ee 's-^<ID>(.*)</ID>-\1-' | sort > 2.txt.ids

comm -12 1.txt.ids 2.txt.ids  | grep -xf IDs.txt
EOF
```

The first `grep` command extracts lines from 1.txt that are entirely composed of 'id=something', then strips off the 'id=' and sorts them into file 1.txt.ids.

The second grep does a similar thing for lines from 2.txt that are entirely composed of '<ID>something</ID>', then strips off the open and closing ID tags, and sorts the ids into 2.txt.ids.

`comm` is then used to show only the lines that appear in both files, and the output of `comm` is further filtered by IDs.txt, which is the list of specific IDs you're interested in.

```
$ cat 1.txt  
id=foo
name=example
age=81
end
id=notTheIDYouAreLookingFor
name=other
age=null
$ cat 2.txt
<Data>
<ID>foo</ID>
<Stuff>Some things</Stuff>
</Data>
<Data>
<ID>bar</ID>
<Stuff>Other things</Stuff>
</Data>
$ cat IDs.txt
foo
bar
someOtherID
$ bash work.sh
foo
```