# exclude regular expression and process very large files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that I need to correct. The words found in the file "exclude.txt" should be removed from original text.

```
original.txt

<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tost" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tast" block-list:name="tart"/>
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="werk" block-list:name="work" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="wark" block-list:name="wrok" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="teble" block-list:name="table" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tetal" block-list:name="total" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="exet" block-list:name="exit" />
```

The exclude file looks like this...

```
exclude.txt
tart
wrok
```

The expected output will look like this...

```
final.txt
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tost" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="werk" block-list:name="work" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="teble" block-list:name="table" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tetal" block-list:name="total" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="exet" block-list:name="exit" />
```

This grep command is working as expected.

```
grep -v -E 'tart|wrok' original.txt
```

This is OK if I have only 2 or 3 words in exclude file. But the problem is that both the original and exclude files have millions of words.

---

Update:

I forgot to mention that I have this line in original.txt

```
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tart" block-list:name="test"/>
```

And I want to keep this line in original file because even if the wrong word "tart" is there, it is not in "**block-list:name**".

---

Update:

The include file has 15 million words compared to exclude file (15 thousand)

```
include.txt
test
work
table
total
exit
```

The awk and grep + sed commands are killed. I will prefer to use include file instead of exclude file (if possible).

Comment: `grep -v -F -w -f exclude.txt original.txt`?

Comment: Yes. Correct. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Only -v -f is working. Why are you adding -F -w ?

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/19380925/3776858](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19380925/3776858)

Comment: To not remove lines that contain strings such as `start`. See: `man grep`

Comment: I'd suggest to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or tools like [hyperscan](https://github.com/intel/hyperscan) for better performance..

Comment: More than expected lines are getting excluded. I will check again and get back with -f option.

Comment: awk solution is better than grep because I want to compare words only in "block-list:name". The placeholder is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk and `"` a delimiter, so basically every even numbered field is a word (`blabla"word"blalbla"another_word"...`):

```
$ awk -F\" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($4 in a)' exclude original
```

Output:

```
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tost" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="werk" block-list:name="work" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="teble" block-list:name="table" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tetal" block-list:name="total" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="exet" block-list:name="exit" />
```

**Edit:** Just noticed *I want to compare words only in "block-list:name". The placeholder is important* in the commants so I changed the `!($2 in a)&&!($4 in a)` to `!($4 in )`. If the placement of `block-list:name` varies, use:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                             # process the exclude file
    a[$1]                             # hash word
    next
}
{                                     # process the original file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # loop every spave separated string
        if($i~/^block-list:name=/) {  # when we meet the desired string
            t=$i                      # copy string to  temp var
            gsub(/^[^"]+"|".*/,"",t)  # extract the word
            if(!(t in a))             # if the word is not to be excluded
                print                 # output record
            next                      # move the next record anyway
        }
}' exclude original
```

Comment: Is it possible to use include file (15 million lines) instead of exclude file (15 thousand)?

Comment: I changed if(!(t in a)) to if((t in a)) while using include file instead of exclude. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `grep + sed` solution in `bash`:

```sh
grep -vFf <(sed 's/.*/block-list:name="&"/' exclude.txt) original.txt

<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tost" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="werk" block-list:name="work" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="teble" block-list:name="table" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tetal" block-list:name="total" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="exet" block-list:name="exit" />
```

- `sed 's/.*/block-list:name="&"/' exclude.txt` is used to wrap each word in `exclude.txt` with `block-list:name="<word>"`
- `grep -vFf` is used to match all non-matching lines from `original.txt` with the patterns coming from a process substitution ``<(....)`that runs`sed` command.

PS: Based on the edited question, this solution only ignore `block-list:name="blocked-word"` in original file.

Comment: This solution is better than awk because non-standard lines are preserved. And I do not need to learn awk to use this command. :)

Comment: This works for exclude list. But if I replace the file with include list and remove -v flag, the command gets killed. This is because the include file has 15 million lines while exclude file has only 15 thousand.